# Should I use "this" keyword to access class members from inside member functions?

Tags: c++, function, oop

```
template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector() : _size_(0){
    this->_capacity_ = 10;
    buffer = new T[this->_capacity_];
}
template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int s) {
        this->_size_ = s;
        this->_capacity_ = _size_;
        this->buffer = new T[this->_capacity_];
        init(0, this->_size_);
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(unsigned int s, const T &initial){
    this->_size_ = s;
    this->_capacity_ = s;   
    this->buffer = new T[this->_capacity_];
    init(0, s, initial);
}
```

My code uses the `this` keyword a lot. Is it considered good practice to call member functions within a class rather than just access it directly, without the `this` keyword? If I always call member functions to access member variables, would it incur overhead? What do the C++ implementations do?

Comment: Is your question whether or not to use `this` to access members/methods or is it whether or not to use getters and setters instead of accessing members directly? It's not clear to me.

Comment: You _shouldn't_ use `this`. It bulks up the code and makes it less readable. Why use C++ if you want to type out your `this`? It looks "odd" (ie no-one writes code like that, it's crazy).

Answer (score 7):

There is no overhead because the code is compiled. When you do:

```
this->_size = 5;
```

and

```
_size=5
```

The compiler treats them as identical and produces identical code.

If you like using 'this' then use it.

Personally I don't like it.

Comment: I'm not referring to using this or not. I'm talking about invoking an accessor function within a class. However, its nice to learn that the compiler optimizes the use of this. But isn't this a pointer?

Comment: @user246694 Yes, it's a pointer but you still have to go through it to access _size, wether you tell the compiler explicitly (`this->_size`) or implicitly.

Comment: `I'm not referring to using this or not.` Effectively, you do :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you initialize members in your constructors is wrong. You should use initializer lists:

```
struct X {
  X() : a(1), b(2), c(3) {}
  int a, b, c;
};
```

otherwise the value will have to be default initialized and reset afterwards.

The cost of accessing non-virtual member functions is hard to calculate because it depends on inlining. If it is inlined, it is overhead free. This is very likely for simple get/setters.

For virtual member functions it depends on the capability of the compiler to possibly hoist the virtual call at compile time, but you should assume that there will be overhead.

Comment: Cannot the compiler figure out the initialisation. What would the default for 'a' be?

Comment: @Rob This depends on the type of the value being initialized and if the `class` is POD or not. As a rule of thumb: always use initializer lists to initialize all values.